# Scalable way to retrieve user detail for multiple user id present in a record, where as for each record there are more than 1 userId

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I have an array of n records whereas in each record(i) the is a userId (j) which is more than 1 for each record(i). So my question is what is a more optimal way to fetch the user detail via user id for all the records in node.js?

**FYI** My Backend is **Node** and Database is **Couchbase**.

For your reference I have added one sample data of my record:-

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "appId": "f6e9f71c-d1b6-45c1-a2f3-e5b3a668646c",
            "attributes": {
                "activity": "Adhoc",
                "assignedTo": "INE12400425",  //userId
                "assignedBy": "INE12400638",  //userId
                "reviewedBy": "INE12400444",  //userId
                "status": "Submitted",
                "targetDate": "22/06/2023",
            },
            "taskId": "CPDS1687342056400",
            "type": "task",
            "updatedDateTime": "12/07/2023 01:55"
        },
        {
            "appId": "f6e9f71c-d1b6-45c1-a2f3-e5b3a668646c",
            "attributes": {
                "activity": "Data Dictionary",
                "assignedTo": "INE12400425",   //userId
                "assignedBy": "INE12400638",   //userId
                "reviewedBy": "INE12400444",   //userId
                "status": "Submitted",
                "targetDate": "30/06/2023"
            },
            "taskId": "CPDS1687341243671",
            "type": "task",
            "updatedDateTime": "21/06/2023 19:17"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you can see in the above sample data '**assignedTo**', '**assignedBy**' and '**reviewedBy**' are 3 fields where user id is stored. Now while sending response it has to sent as below :-

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "appId": "f6e9f71c-d1b6-45c1-a2f3-e5b3a668646c",
            "attributes": {
                "activity": "Adhoc",
                "assignedTo": "Sweta Sharma",    //userName
                "assignedBy": "Anuj Yadav",     //userName
                "reviewedBy": "Rahul Kumar",   //userName
                "status": "Submitted",
                "targetDate": "22/06/2023",
            },
            "taskId": "CPDS1687342056400",
            "type": "task",
            "updatedDateTime": "12/07/2023 01:55"
        },
        {
            "appId": "f6e9f71c-d1b6-45c1-a2f3-e5b3a668646c",
            "attributes": {
                "activity": "Data Dictionary",
                "assignedTo": "Sweta Sharma",   //userName
                "assignedBy": "Anuj Yadav",    //userName
                "reviewedBy": "Rahul Kumar",   //userName
                "status": "Submitted",
                "targetDate": "30/06/2023"
            },
            "taskId": "CPDS1687341243671",
            "type": "task",
            "updatedDateTime": "21/06/2023 19:17"
        }
    ]
}
```

For you reference I am adding the user document below :-

```
{
    "type": "userInfo",
    "userName": "Sweta Sharma",
    "employeeNumber": "INE12400425",
    "id": "1adb05db-6e3f-432f-96d2-b6ed37836ee7"
}

{
    "type": "userInfo",
    "userName": "Anuj Yadav",
    "employeeNumber": "INE12400638",
    "id": "1adb05db-6e3f-432f-96d2-b6ed37836de7"
}

{
    "type": "userInfo",
    "userName": "Rahul Kumar",
    "employeeNumber": "INE12400444",
    "id": "1adb05db-6e3f-432f-96d2-b6ed37836fe7"
}
```

I have tried few way but the scalability is not good.

Option 1 :-
Loop through all the records and make repeated query for every user id to get the user details from the database which is obviously not optimal.

Option 2 :-
Keep all the user records in the node cache and fetch the user info for every record which will again result in running the loop n times for n records.
This is again not optimal.

Any other approach? Any suggestion will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

> Option 1 :- Loop through all the records and make repeated query for every user id to get the user details from the database which is obviously not optimal.

Actually shouldn't be the worst option and gives you the flexibility to scale the requests across multiple threads in your application and also distribute across all the nodes of Couchbase.  An index on userID,userName should get you those back very quickly.

Depending on the requirements of your API and frontend, it's a fairly common approach to return a list of items and then query on-demand for the details behind each one.  For instance, if the UI is displaying a list of tasks but not showing the user names, you can then query for the user names when an individual task is requested.  This also helps cut down on the amount of data being transferred if it's not needed.

If you do require all of the userNames to be fully populated, have you tried using JOIN in the query?  You'll be able to index those three fields, but keep in mind that array indexes can get quite large depending on how many elements you have in tasks[].  If you have the flexibility to do so, changing the data model so that each task is in its own document would reduce the size of the index but it's not required from a functional perspective.